# pdf.js giving back "InvalidPDFException: Invalid Pdf Structure"

Tags: javascript, java, angular, pdf.js

I currently have a backend java service that converts html to pdfs for me using itext.  I return the pdf as a byte[] just fine to the client(**Angular 5**).  But I end up getting *"invalid pdf structure"* when I try running the getDocument function on it.  I do not believe that the pdf structure is actually invalid.  I uploaded my html template to an online pdf converter and it worked just fine.

This is what I'm getting from the backend:

[image]

This is my pdfjs code:

```
class MyDocumentsProvider{
      downloadPdf():any{
    return this.http.get(environment.webappServer+"/get1098E", {responseType:'arraybuffer'}).map(
      (res) =>{
          return res;
        }
      )
  }
}
this.myDocumentsProvider.downloadPdf().subscribe((res)=>{
        PDFJS.disableWorker = true; //<-- removing this does nothing

        PDFJS.getDocument(res).then((pdf)=>{
          this.showLoader = false;
            this.pdf = pdf;
            this.pagesTotal = pdf.numPages;
            pdf.getPage(this.pageNum).then((page) => {
                this.handlePages(page);
          this.writeFile();
            })
        }).catch((err)=>{
            this.showError = true;
        console.error(err);
        })
    },((err)=>{
      this.showError = true;
      console.error(err);
    }))
}
```

I've also tried doing

```
    PDFJS.getDocument(new Uint8Array(res))then((pdf)...
```

I have tested this code with direct url to a pdf file and it works.

This is some java code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/testPdf",  headers="Accept=*/*", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> testPdf() throws IOException{


        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type","application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8"); //<-- this was added later on.  Did nothing....
        ResponseEntity <byte[]> arr = pdfService.htmlTemplateToPdf()
        return new ResponseEntity<>(arr,responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Please lend me your assistance fellow SOs!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of :

```
return this.http.get(environment.webappServer+"/get1098E", {responseType:'arraybuffer'}).map(
  (res) =>{
      return res;
    }
  )
```

I just removed the responseType:'arraybuffer'.
Then I took the response and manually converted it into a typed array (Uint8Array).
I guess responseType:arraybuffer was giving back something corrupted.

Comment: Hi. Can you show how you converted it? Many thanks!